# Noisy sound on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, services, sound-card, noise

**The problem:** 
When I let sound play (from Spotify, videogames, making music...) for some time, what seems like white noise eventually appears.

**My setup:**
A desktop running windows 10, with an external sound card, a small mix table, connected to two external stereo speakers.

**Observations:**

- Before the external sound card was added, there was no problem.
- Restarting the audio service temporarily fixes the problem: `Restart-Service audiosrv`.

I don't know much about sound hardware or Windows' audio server so I'm not sure where the problem comes from.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  You mention an "external sound card" but didn't provide details on the card itself.  The fact restarting a service indicate this likely is linked to a driver problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will add more information (and try what the first answer suggests) as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

Likely, somewhere in the chain of audio software and devices, there's automatic volume control (AVC), compression, or level normalization processing. If the sound card is handling stereo or [multiple sound channels](https://thehometheaterdiy.com/surround-sound-channels-explained/), and if some of those channels have *no* signal, then the sound processing could slowly attempt to boost gain on that channel until it reaches maximum, producing white noise, or even 50/60 Hz hum.

Using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), for example, here are two effects that could cause slowly increasing background noise:

[image: Loudness Normalization dlg]

[image: Compressor dlg]

Note that these dialogs show settings to prevent that noise, e.g., *don't* `Normalize stereo channels independently`, and `Noise floor`. Also notice the `Attack time` and `Release time` settings, which would control how long it takes for noise to rise.

What you can do:

- Check that all channels have volume slaved together, if feasible.
- Turn off, whether in  the sound-card control settings or in software, all unused sound channels.
- Set a noise floor, below which sounds are *not* amplified.